# How put image to more than one tab in excel sheets

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have a problem adding a picture to another sheet. I have no problem adding a picture to the sheet which is the first or only one. I have no idea how to solve it.

It also looks in no easy way POI does not allow you to add images to other sheets

Thank you in advance for any help with this problem

Example code :

```
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

import org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;


class ImageTest {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {

   Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
   Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("My Sample Excel");
   //FileInputStream obtains input bytes from the image file
   InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("/home/axel/Bilder/Wasserlilien.jpg");
   //Get the contents of an InputStream as a byte[].
   byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
   //Adds a picture to the workbook
   int pictureIdx = wb.addPicture(bytes, Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG);
   //close the input stream
   inputStream.close();
   //Returns an object that handles instantiating concrete classes
   CreationHelper helper = wb.getCreationHelper();
   //Creates the top-level drawing patriarch.
   Drawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();

   //Create an anchor that is attached to the worksheet
   ClientAnchor anchor = helper.createClientAnchor();

   //create an anchor with upper left cell _and_ bottom right cell
   anchor.setCol1(1); //Column B
   anchor.setRow1(2); //Row 3
   anchor.setCol2(2); //Column C
   anchor.setRow2(3); //Row 4

   //Creates a picture
   Picture pict = drawing.createPicture(anchor, pictureIdx);

   //Reset the image to the original size
   //pict.resize(); //don't do that. Let the anchor resize the image!

   //Create the Cell B3
   Cell cell = sheet.createRow(2).createCell(1);

   //set width to n character widths = count characters * 256
   //int widthUnits = 20*256;
   //sheet.setColumnWidth(1, widthUnits);

   //set height to n points in twips = n * 20
   //short heightUnits = 60*20;
   //cell.getRow().setHeight(heightUnits);

   //Write the Excel file
   FileOutputStream fileOut = null;
   fileOut = new FileOutputStream("myFile.xlsx");
   wb.write(fileOut);
   fileOut.close();

  } catch (IOException ioex) {
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Your code is only creating an image on the first sheet, and you already know that that works. Post an [mcve] that tries to create one on another sheet, and clearly describe how it is failing (are you getting any specific error message anywhere). From this code, I don't understand why it would go wrong if you do `Drawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();` on the second or the third sheet.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends what you're looking to do. If you want to insert a picture in the same spot on multiple sheets, then you can just put your code into a loop like this:

```
try {
    Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();

    //FileInputStream obtains input bytes from the image file
    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("C:\\path\\to\\image\\image.jpg");
    //Get the contents of an InputStream as a byte[].
    byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
    //Adds a picture to the workbook
    int pictureIdx = wb.addPicture(bytes, Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG);
    //close the input stream
    inputStream.close();

    //Returns an object that handles instantiating concrete classes
    CreationHelper helper = wb.getCreationHelper();

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Sheet Number " + i);
        //Creates the top-level drawing patriarch.
        Drawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();

        //Create an anchor that is attached to the worksheet
        ClientAnchor anchor = helper.createClientAnchor();

        //create an anchor with upper left cell _and_ bottom right cell
        anchor.setCol1(1); //Column B
        anchor.setRow1(2); //Row 3
        anchor.setCol2(2); //Column C
        anchor.setRow2(3); //Row 4

        //Creates a picture
        Picture pict = drawing.createPicture(anchor, pictureIdx);

        //Create the Cell B3
        Cell cell = sheet.createRow(2).createCell(1);
    }

    //Write the Excel file
    FileOutputStream fileOut = null;
    fileOut = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Temp\\myFile.xlsx");
    wb.write(fileOut);
    fileOut.close();
} catch (IOException ioex) {
    ioex.printStackTrace();
}
```

This code creates an Excel file with three sheets and places the image in the same spot on all three of them. I've just tested this and it works fine. If you're looking to place it in different spots on multiple sheets, you should be able to extrapolate how to do that from this code as well. You can either use the loop with if/case statements or just sequentially create your sheets.